# Adding multiple IP Addresses to a single NIC

Tags: python, node.js, windows, networking

I need to write a script using Python or Javascript where I can simulate 100 unique IP addresses on a single NIC in a Windows environment.

For example, I am connected via Ethernet to a switch with my PC statically assigned to `172.30.10.1` and I want to add 100 IPs ranging from `172.30.10.1 to 172.30.10.100` on a single NIC.

In Windows, you're able to add IP's and ports using Control panel but I found little to no information on if such a thing is possible using one of the mentioned languages to accomplish this.

[Windows 10 adding multiple IP addresses to a single NIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6OHi.png)

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/51741/how-to-quickly-add-multiple-ip-addresses-to-windows-servers/ (and maybe using Python's `subprocess` module to call the `netsh` command).

Comment: Was really hoping there was some library but this looks like it will work. I will give it a go.